# How to auto login with Firebase in Android Studio?

Tags: java, android, firebase, sharedpreferences, autologin

I am creating a restaurant app for members & non-members. The home page consist of 3 buttons- menu, sign-in and sign-up. I want to let non-members auto login (default phoneId)into the system when they tap on the *menu button* and members will just sign-in or sign-up each time.

I tried to use sharedPreferences (default phoneId) for the non-member auto login but I don't know whether the default phoneId can be sync with firebase. I want to track the transaction orders for the non-members. Is there any way to only let the default phoneId to have auto login function?

p/s I am just a beginner and doing this app for my project. pls help thanks.

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

Button btnSignIn, btnSignUp, btnMenu;
public AppPreferences appPreference;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    appPreference = new AppPreferences(this);

    btnMenu = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnMenu);
    btnSignUp = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnSignUp);
    btnSignIn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnSignIn);



    btnMenu.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            Intent home = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Home.class);
            //Here save user info to preferences
            appPreference.setUserPhoneId(Constant.DEFAULT_PHONE_ID);
            appPreference.setUserPassword(Constant.DEFAULT_PASSWORD);
            startActivity(home);


        }
    });

    btnSignUp.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            Intent signUp = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SignUp.class);
            startActivity(signUp);
        }
    });

    btnSignIn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            Intent signIn = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SignIn.class);
            startActivity(signIn);
        }
    });
}
}
```

AppPreferences.java

```
public class AppPreferences {

// Class variables
private Context context;
private static SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;
private static SharedPreferences.Editor editor;
public static final String PREF_NAME = "iMenuApp";
private int PRIVATE_MODE = 0;

// Define your preferences key
private static final String USER_PHONE = "9876543210";
private static final String USER_PASSWORD = "12345";

public AppPreferences(Context context)
{
    this.context = context;
    sharedPreferences = this.context.getSharedPreferences(PREF_NAME, PRIVATE_MODE);

    if (sharedPreferences != null)
    {
        editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
    }
}

//Store user PhoneId


public void setUserPhoneId(String userId){
    String TAG = "AppPref:setUserId";
    try
    {
        editor.putString(USER_PHONE, userId);
        editor.commit();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(TAG, String.valueOf(e));
    }
}

// Get userPhoneId
public String getUserPhoneId(){
    return sharedPreferences.getString(USER_PHONE,"default_phone");
}

//Store userPassword
public void setUserPassword(String userPassword){
    String TAG = "AppPref:setUserPassword";
    try
    {
        editor.putString(USER_PASSWORD, userPassword);
        editor.commit();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(TAG, String.valueOf(e));
    }
}

// Get userPassword
public String getUserPassword(){
    return sharedPreferences.getString(USER_PASSWORD,"default_password");
}


}
```

Answer (score 1):

the whole approach is rather questionable, because there is an [anonymous authentication provider](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/anonymous-auth), which should be used for those "non-members" (and it can also be used together with security rules). storing the state of the authentication to `Preferences` is prone to errors, because it does not consider the actual state of the authentication - which will result in `access denied`, once the token expired.

I've also seen your previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52688785/how-to-store-a-default-value-in-sharedpreferences), while nevertheless the whole business logic is flawed.

... better see [AccountManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/accounts/AccountManager), for how to properly store accounts on Android.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do something like this,

`MainActivity` -> `SignIn` -> if SignIn success -> Next time you launch the app land to `Home` Activity

Try this,

1.) First, you define a new `boolean` preferences key, `USER_LOGGED_IN` and create `setUserLoggedIn()` and `getUserLoggedIn()` methods in your `AppPreferences` class as below.

```
    private static final boolean USER_LOGGED_IN = false;

     public static void setUserLoggedIn(boolean value) {
                String TAG = "AppPref:setUserLoggedIn";
        try{
            editor.putBoolean(USER_LOGGED_IN, value);
            editor.commit();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(TAG, String.valueOf(e));
        }
     }

    public static boolean getUserLoggedIn() {
        return sharedPreferences.getBoolean(USER_LOGGED_IN, false);       
    }
```

2.) Then, in your `SignIn` Activity, If login success, set UserLoggedIn as `true` in your `sharedPreferences`.

3.) Finally, In your `MainActivity`, `override` `onResume()` method as follows,

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    boolean userLoggedIn = AppPreferences.getUserLoggedIn();

    if(userLoggedIn){
        MainActivity.this.startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Home.class).setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK));
    }
}
```

Try this and let me know your feedback.
Thanks!